# Can't decode some characters in php (like single quote)

Tags: php, character-encoding

I converted some pdfs using php but I still have some characters that I can't be endoded/decoded using utf8 functions.
For example the single quotes are shown as a rectangle with little number inside (00 92), I'll put it next but don't think it will appear:

I tried with utf8_encode and utf8_decode, even several time, but never get a single quote.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using this [link](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) it says that there is only character for "single quotes", i.e. apostrophe. For some reason, those single quotes are different than the normal apostrophe. Actually there are 2 of them: left single quote and right single quote

Try using this link to [UTF-16](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm), which explains right single quote.

Hope this helps